# 3 States CheckBox in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, web

I have seen multiple posts regarding 3 states checkbox using directive as well as using css-tricks (indeterminate=true ,is not working.)

But i want to ask if there is another possible way to acheive 3 states checkbox for 3 different values (true, false and null).

Visually 3 states will be

1. Checked
2. UNchecked (blank)
3. Indeterminate (Full coloured or something.)

Answer (score 1):

To make a checkbox show an indeterminate state, use the `ng-prop-indeterminate` directive to set the `indeterminate` property of the element.

## The DEMO

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    <input type="checkbox"
           ng-model="checkState"
           ng-prop-indeterminate="triState">
    The Check Box<br>
    <hr>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkState">CheckState={{checkState}}<br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="triState">TriState={{triState}}<br>
</body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-prop Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngProp)
- [MDN HTML Element Reference - input type="checkbox"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox)

Comment: hey thanks @georgeawg. I tried this solution. I assigned a function to the ng-prop-indeterminate, but it isnt working, the function also is not called. I also read the documents , but that dint help either.

Comment: This answers the question of how to display a checkbox in a tri-state mode. Problems on how to use the `ng-prop` directive with a function should be asked as a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Be sure to include code that people can easily understand and [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).